# nginx does not redirect to secure site

Tags: asp.net, docker, nginx

I am new to nginx and following directions from https://codeburst.io/load-balancing-an-asp-net-core-web-app-using-nginx-and-docker-66753eb08204 to setup/test
However the redirection from http to https doesn't work for some reason, from what i understand

```
server {
    listen     *:80 default_server;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    return     301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

this should redirect all http to https but instead i get this in firefox

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

environment is localhost/firefox/asp.net 5/nginx on wsl/ubuntu

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: 'nginx'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/proxy.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl/localhost.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt:ro
      - ./nginx/ssl/localhost.key:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost.key:ro
      - ./nginx/logs/:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      - api
    restart: always

  api:
    build: ./src
    ports:
      - '5000'
    restart: always
```

Comment: Can you open developer tools in your browser and see whether redirect is happening? This is how it should be if there was a redirect https://i.imgur.com/09RBlGY.png

Comment: @anemyte no redirects https://imgur.com/a/uY0YK9Z

Comment: Please add docker-compose file that you use.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this. I've cloned the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet-labs/NginxLoadBalancer) but it works for me as expected.